# Unable to view Information spaces in Explorer

Tags: business-objects, business-objects-sdk

Hi we've created an explorer. It runs fine but however it goes missing from the information space list very often and upon re-indexing, it used to re-appear back. However today even after re-indexing n number of times, it doesn't show up.

I've checked it's universe security and user security settings in CMC with the rest of the explorers to see if it's any different from the rest and found all of them similar.

Can you please help me or advice me as where I'm missing out.

--VJAI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this the correct Issue.But I found out that this happens only when the explorer is either opened or Users try to open it while it's being indexed.:-(